# Position the UITableView correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I am making a `UITableView` programatically. I have a `UIView` and a `UISearchBar` that should not be hidden away by the `UITableView`. How will I get the frame to fit perfectly in the screen. X & Y co-ordinates should not overlap the `UIView` and `UISearchBar`. The width should hold be exactly the width of the search bar and the view should end with the last cell.

Comment: Not getting your question. Share screen  shot of expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Change the position according to your requirements

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 44)];
```